# cannot dynamically change page using angular js method

Tags: angularjs

This is the Angular JS function on my page:

```
function DateCtrl($scope) {

        $scope.returndate = function () {

            return Date.now();
        }

    }
```

The markup is as follows:

```
<html ng-app>
<body>    
<div id = "date" class = "stats" ng-controller = "DateCtrl">
            <span>Date:</span><div id = "noedate">{{returndate()}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You would expect the date returned in `#nowdate` to change every second thanks to the data-binding, but it does not. Does anyone know what is wrong here?

I would provide a fiddle but jsfiddle does not support angular yet...

Comment: AngularJS works perfectly with jsFiddle, check this: http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data won't get updated automatically since AngularJS doesn't constantly pool for changes but only refreshes templates in response to certain events. You can check this post: [How does data binding work in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs/9693933#9693933) for more info on inner workings of angular.

If you would like to refresh certain value after a given period of time use the $timeout service (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout).

Actually it is very easy to do a clock in AngularJS using combination of $watch and $timeout:

```
$scope.time = new Date();  
$scope.$watch('time', function(){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.time = new Date();
    },1000);
});
```

Here is the complete jsFillde: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/f5ApP/1/

Comment: I suppose so, but doesnt this defeat the point of the databinding feature? -_-

Comment: @codeninja, to have data-binding to update a template automatically you need to decide _when_ to update. There are many options: refresh periodicity, pool for changes or refresh on certain events. AngularJS have chosen to update DOM (after dirty-checking) in response to certain events (user action, xhr calls, location changes etc.). This is just a design choice you need to be aware of when working with AngularJS.

Comment: How is that supposed to work? When I try something like this it only executes the timedout function once. I don't use the time but a textual representation. I presume watch doesn't check after it was the same twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
var updateTime = function () {
    $scope.currentTime = new Date();
    $timeout(updateTime, 1000);
};
updateTime();
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could add a brief explanation of your code.